# How to get a relation to user in a DreamFactory app?

Tags: authentication, dreamfactory

I am using DreamFactory on the server of a webapp. I have created all the tables in the DreamFactory local MySql database, but how do I add the relation the built in users? All user objects in the app will be stored in built in user table that comes with DreamFactory (/api/v2/system/user).

So, is there a way to actually make the relation from my custom tables to the built in user table, or do I need to duplicate the user data in my own user table in my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new user table in my web app, mirroring the user table used by DreamFactory. I did manage to set up the default "system" as a service, and linking tho this service, but then all the user information stored on the user was sent to my web app. So my best option was then to create my custom user table with the id set to the same as the DreamFactory user table. Not a perfect solution, but it will work for now